# Class '<full path to class>' could not be found in '<full path to class.php>' phpunit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to work with phpunit for testing.

I have a file that looks like this (for trial):

```
<?php
class NewController {
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }


}
```

When I run phpunit (v. 5.2) - I see the following error:

```
Class 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\NewController' could not be found in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\NewController.php'.
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing - but another set of eyes might help out.

Comment: How do you load your class? Do you use composer with its autoloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear there was a problem with the installation of phpunit.  Once uninstalled/reinstalled it is working without issue.